# Cancelling a task scheduled in a ScheduledExecutorService keeps executor alive

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

This has been bugging me for a few hours now.. If I schedule a task to be executed in **5 seconds** and then cancel that task immediately I would expect the "awaitTermination" method to return immediately, but it keeps blocking for the full **7 seconds** (not five)..

Here is a JUnit 5 test case that reproduces the issue on Java 11.

```
package dummy;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

class DummyTest {

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Cancelling task should work...")
  void cancel_task() throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    AtomicBoolean isExecuted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduled = executorService.schedule(() -> isExecuted.set(true), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    scheduled.cancel(false);

    if (!executorService.awaitTermination(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      fail("Didn't shut down within timeout"); // <-- Fails here
    }

    assertFalse(isExecuted.get(), "Task should be cancelled before executed");
  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)): "Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't call shutdown or shutdownNow on your executorService, so you can wait forever. It will never terminate. Call shutdown first, then the unit test should work.

```
scheduled.cancel(false);
executorService.shutdown(); // This was missing
if (!executorService.awaitTermination(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
...
```

[awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) "Blocks until all tasks have completed execution **after a shutdown request**, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first" (copied from comments, thanks ptomli).

Comment: Might be useful to add a link to the reference documentation, which says
> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: Ah, damn I forgot that when trying to reproduce the my problem in isolation. It obviously works when I call shutdown first. Then I guess the problem is elsewhere. Thanks :-)

Comment: Looks like I'm struggling with this https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7069418